# Why does my program block while reading line from BufferedReader?

Tags: java, adb

I am executing some commands using ProcessBuilder as follows:

```
BufferedReader response = null;
process = processBuilder.start();           
response = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

But code blocks at following line, while read line from response.

```
while((line = response.readLine()) != null) {
  /* some code here */
}
```

I did some google and I found that when readLine() not get EOL then it will block.

How can I make it work or resolve that issue.

Comment: one of the way around is that you can read bytes, while((i=bufferreader.read(buffer,i,100))!= -1)
{
 //do work
}

Comment: Looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792835/how-do-you-set-a-timeout-on-bufferedreader-and-printwriter-in-java-1-4

Comment: Terminology please. The word is 'block', not 'hang out'.

Answer (score 1):

According to the API, this is what is indicated for `readLine()`

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

So i think you'll have to make sure you are providing line terminator to avoid blocking.

Comment: How do I set line terminator? The response is returned by executing process builder. Just I can read it. right?

Comment: line = response.readLine() I dont get any response or string at this line. So I am unable to append '\n' at the end of line.

Comment: @Addict comment should sort that out, read `bytes` instead of `lines`